# NSMutableDictionary -- using allKeysforObject not retrieving array values

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSMutableDictionary *expense_ArrContents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
for (int i = 1; i<=4; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *current_row = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"payer_id",@"Expense_Type_id",@"Category_Id",@"SubCategory_Id",nil];
    [expense_ArrContents setObject:current_row forKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
NSArray *newArray = [expense_ArrContents allKeysForObject:@"payer_id"];
NSLog(@"%@",[newArray description]);
```

i want to get the list of key values containing the particular object which is in the array of values stored in nsmutabledictionary for a particular key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line where you get all the keys (`[expense_ArrContents allKeysForObject:@"payer_id"];`) you actually get keys for an object that is not in any of the array's items. This `@"player_id"` is different object than the `@"player_id"` you added in `current_row`. In fact, maybe all of your rows have different `@"player_id"` objects (except if the compiler has made some optimization - maybe it threats that same string literal as one object instead of creating new object for each iteration).
Try creating an NSString object for the `@"player_id"` which you add to the `current_row` and then get all the keys for that same object:

```
NSString* playerId = @"player_id";
for(){
    NSMutableArray *current_row = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: playerId,...];
...
}
NSArray *newArray = [expense_ArrContents allKeysForObject:playerId];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your NSArray `*newArray = [expense_ArrContents allKeysForObject:@"payer_id"];` will not return any value because in  expense_ArrContents there is no such key(@"payer_id"), instead there are keys like 1,2,3 etc.What is your requirement?Want to see what all keys are there in expense_ArrContents just log

```
NSArray*keys=[expense_ArrContents allKeys];
```

Comment: I want to get the list of keys containing the particular objectvalue which is in the array of nsmutabledictionary

Comment: But your dictionary does not contain any object which is @"payer_id", on the other hand it contains array as an object which has this object. And all key will have this object according to your code.So on what basis you are finding that which key contains this object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSMutableArray *array_key=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSString *key in expense_ArrContents) {    
    if ([[expense_ArrContents objectForKey:key] containsObject:@"payer_id"]) {
        [array_key addObject:key];
    }
}
```